# web api FromUri and FromBody attributes misunderstanding

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I found this example in google:

```
 public string GetValue([FromUri]Book b, [FromUri]Author a)
 {
     return b.Name + " ("+a.AuthorName+")";
 }

 public string PostValue([FromBody]Person p)
 {
     return  p.FirstName;
 }
```

I can't understand what is the point of **[FromUri]** attribute if HTTP GET method send data only as part of the URl  respectively, what's the point of **[FromBody]** attribute to use it in HTTP POST method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/) article explain why the **[FromUri]** is necessary and how to workaround to not need write it anymore.

> Web API will always try to eagerly bind non-primitive and non-string covnertible types from the body of the request. While in many cases that’s all right, semantically, it doesn’t make much sense for GET and HEAD requests, since in accordance to the HTTP specification, these are body-less requests.

The **[FromBody]** is usei to force Web API to read a simple type from the request body. In your sample, Person is already a complex type, so that attribute is not necessary. Worth to say yet, that you cannot use two parameters with **FromBody**, like said [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).